# Having trouble creating a table in SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm refreshing my memory on SQL and I'm having trouble creating a table in SQL*Plus. I'm following an example and I've typed exactly what the example has but the error I'm getting is:
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

```
CREATE TABLE acctmanger
  2  (amid CHAR(4),
  3  amfirst VARCHAR2(12),
  4  amlast VARCHAR2(12),
  5  amdate DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
  6  amsal NUMBER(8,2),
  7  amcomm NUMBER(7,2) DEFAULT 0,
  8  amearn AS (amsal + amcomm),
  9  region CHAR(2));
```

Comment: delete 2,3, 4 ...8,9 characters and try again

Comment: Please tag your question properly!!!  SQL *Plus is for Oracle, but why do I see MySQL tag on your question?

Comment: Changed [tag:mysql] to [tag:oracle].

Comment: You wrote in your question: _I'm following an example_ Care to provide the link to that example?

Comment: The script works well in Oracle: See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a9f0db96e5fc0c0cea60ace077248401

Comment: Which Oracle database version do you use?